# Sidekiq doesn't run queue with carrierwave_backgrounder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, sidekiq

this is my first atemp to run sidekiq and carrierwave_backgrounder

After all when I check my redis data, I can see there is a key: queue:images with params:

```
{"retry":true, "queue":"images", "class":"CarrierWave::Workers::StoreAsset","args":["Image", "6", "image"] ... }
```

Anyway, I have my sideqik running with "bundle exec sidekiq" but it does nothing. The images are not processed and the queues in the redis database are still present.

I should mentioned that I did not configure the sidekiq at all. All is running locally. Rails4 server, sidekiq and redis.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the problem. I did not specify the queue in the sidekiq.

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q images
```

solved the problem.